# How to deal with SpiderWebPlot in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, jfreereport

Discovering JFreeChart, I hit a problem using [SpiderWebPlot](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/plot/SpiderWebPlot.html).

This is what I have today

[image]

My values are {2, 2, 1.5}

By default max value is set to the max value of my dataset (here 2) but I want to set it to 5 which as you can see it did but it did not draw the lines for the value between 2 and 5.

How can I progamatically draw them ?

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT** :

```
SpiderWebPlot plot = (SpiderWebPlot)chart.getPlot();
plot.setMaxValue(5.00);
plot.setHeadPercent(0.01);

return chart;
```

I am using JFreeChart through another application that gives me the hand directly on the chart variable. So that the piece of code I introduced.

Comment: Please post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that reproduces the plot shown.

Comment: See also this [forum thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115667) that cites a related patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lines shown do not appear to be a feature of [`JFreeChart`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/). This may be an anomaly introduced by whomever extended the [code](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/plot/SpiderWebPlot.java), with which your version should be compared.