# JFreeChart SpiderWebPlot inner circles?

Tags: jfreechart

So I have been using JFreeChart to try and create spiderWebPlot and it's been working well so far:

[image]

I was wondering if it was possible to add circles for the possibles values, so it looks more like an actual spider web, something like:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding above code patch you will get rings like below image.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501702/230513), a background grid is not yet implemented. A [patch](https://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/patches/139/) is cited and discussed in this [forum thread](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=115667).